# Spring Declarative Transaction. Custom PreInterceptors based on transactionAttributes

Tags: spring, transactions, interceptor

I have a spring Transaction defined as below -

```
<bean id="ServiceTransactions"  class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
        <property name="optimize" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
            <property name="preInterceptors">
        <list>
            <bean id="readOnlyConnectionMethodInterceptor" class="com.dealer.framework.dao.interceptor.ReadOnlyConnectionMethodInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

I want to make sure the `readOnlyConnectionMethodInterceptor` applies to only methods that start with find* and not to other methods.

I could not find any information in the spring docs about this.

I am wondering if some one could shed a light on how to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no support on the Spring side for this. 
I had a create a hackish way of checking the method name in the preinterceptor before choosing to take Action.

Somewhat like this -

```
class CustomInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

      if(invocation.getMethod().getName().startsWith("foo"){
          //Take appropriate Action
      }
      invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```